# Passthru printing via PuTTY/KiTTY to Konica Minolta Bizhub Multifunctional Printers secured by PageScope

Tags: putty, kitty

We have been unable to passthru print using PuTTY (or its offshoot KiTTY) to several Konica Minolta multifunctional printers which are secured by KM's PageScope. I have been able to get Procomm Plus 4.8 and another terminal emulator, QVT Term to print to these printers. However the latter software does not work on Windows 7, so we have gone to KiTTY to replace it.

I talked with our vendor of the KM Printers and he thinks it may be because the Putty/Kitty data stream may not be acquiring the user credentials.  He thought that if KiTTY could use the windows default printer, that would solve the problem.

I created a dummy printer with the Bizhub printer driver, but the port being a file, and captured the output therefrom as it is presented to the printer.  The output from QVTTerm and Procomm are formatted correctly for the printer.  However that from Kitty remains the unformatted input file.